# JPA CriteriaQuery: How to join to table via id

Tags: java, jpa, spring-boot

Let's suppose I have these two entities(It's more complex in my code):

```
Product {
  private Long id;
  private String name;
  private Long category_id;
}

Category {
  private Long id;
  private String name;
}
```

I need to find all products under a specified category, like this:

```
SELECT p FROM t_product p,t_category c WHERE p.category_id = c.id AND c.name = 'Hello'
```

Now I want to perform this query via JPA CriteriaQuery:

```
Specification<Product> spec = new Specification<Product>() {
      @Override
      public Predicate toPredicate(Root<Product> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder cb) {
      // Do something here
      return null;
}
```

Is there anyway to use `join` in this kind of situation ?

Comment: Why would you need a join? All you need is the equivalent of `select p from Product p where p.category_id = :theId`. Is there a join in that query? That said, you should not store IDs of other entities. You should have a ManyToOne association instead.

Comment: And that still doesn't require any join.

Comment: @JBNizet Shoot, not `p.name`, its `c.name`....

Comment: Use a ManyToOne association.